# Drupal 7 and google maps, distribution or modules

Tags: 7, google-maps, distributions

Throughout my apprenticeship with Drupal 7 I always wondered if it is able to do this:

- http://www.teslamotors.com/findus
- http://bigblogmap.com/

I mean inserting Google map and how it interacts with such websites.

For example: in Teslamotors page, at the top there are buttons: "N. AMERICA EUROPE and ASIA / PACIFIC "and that by giving clik in each, the map is changed geographical position.

Another example that I'm interested in this page (teslamotors) is seen as the pinmaps update when I press the buttons (which are at the bottom center of the map inside): "STORES & GALLERIES" or "service centers." Geographical points are updated and change color.

Similarly we can see the same for the second page I share, on the button: "All Blogs" and see how the updated pinmaps position icons and very dynamic.

Can this be done with Drupal 7? Maybe, I do not know, and there is a distribution which contains all this attached, so I can analyze it and go familiarizing myself more with this fascinating Drupal platform.

Comment: watch this video may be it helps you www.youtube.com/watch?v=iznuDhjAFbg

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this great video, opens the door for me to investigate further.

Those modules will be integrated in a distribution? or project?

regards

Comment: I'm the creator of the www.bigblogmap.com. I don't know much about drupal, but I'm sure that it's possible as I've just turned the same technology into a Wordpress plugin. If you have any specific questions, I can try to help and/or send you the plugin for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the [Open Layers](http://drupal.org/project/openlayers) project and the [Gmap](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) module support google maps. Both can work with a number of geolocation types. See the modules for more details.

I am using both (in different sites) and either one can support what you are trying to accomplish. I would recommend Open Layers as more versatile, and Gmap as easier to use.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Contrib module for this: the [Geolocation](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation) module. Just download it, and install it. It actually it comes with 3 sub-modules you need to enable too.

Then, when you add a new field to to a content type, you will get a new option for a geolocation field.

In case you want to view the locations of all the contents of that content type on a single map, create a view and select the format to be "Geolocation (Google Maps)"; this view will show all the locations of the contents on a single map.

Answer (score 1):

The [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation) and [Geolocation Views](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation_views) modules are a great place to start. Use GF to add geolocation to your custom content types. Use GV for displaying the map as well as the info windows.

There are no README yet. So look into the issue queues of [GF](http://drupal.org/project/issues/geolocation?status=All&categories=All) and [GV](http://drupal.org/project/issues/geolocation_views?status=All&categories=All) for more information.